# Add SonarQube coverage via shields.io badge

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci, shields.io

I have com.github.xxxxxx:xxxxxx Maven repository and I want add shields badge but I have a invalid badge:

https://img.shields.io/sonar/https/sonarqube.com/com.github.noraui:noraui/tech_debt.svg

[image]

Sonarqube xxxxxx project page: https://sonarqube.com/dashboard?id=com.github.xxxxxx%3Axxxxxx

**I find a OK sample from an other sonar server:**

https://img.shields.io/sonar/http/sonar.qatools.ru/ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-core/coverage.svg

https://img.shields.io/sonar/http/sonar.qatools.ru/ru.yandex.qatools.allure:allure-core/tech_debt.svg

[image]

Comment: I find the problem, my sonarqube is version 6.3 and the sonarqube OK is in version 5.1.2:        https://sonarqube.com/web_api/api/resources (deprecated since 5.4)

Comment: https://github.com/badges/shields/issues/877

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now, i do not use http://shields.io but directly the https://sonarcloud.io web site.

```
[![Quality Gate](https://sonarcloud.io/api/badges/gate?key=com.github.noraui:noraui)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard/index/com.github.noraui:noraui)
[![SonarCloud Coverage](https://sonarcloud.io/api/badges/measure?key=com.github.noraui%3Anoraui&metric=coverage)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id=com.github.noraui:noraui)
[![SonarCloud Bugs](https://sonarcloud.io/api/badges/measure?key=com.github.noraui%3Anoraui&metric=bugs)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/reliability_rating/list?id=com.github.noraui%3Anoraui)
[![SonarCloud Vulnerabilities](https://sonarcloud.io/api/badges/measure?key=com.github.noraui%3Anoraui&metric=vulnerabilities)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/security_rating/list?id=com.github.noraui%3Anoraui)
```

[image: Quality Gate]
[image: SonarCloud Coverage]
[image: SonarCloud Bugs]
[image: SonarCloud Vulnerabilities]

Comment: This won't work. Check for the new apis below. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54266444/1097600

Answer (score 16):

### New APIS.

```
 [![Sonarcloud Status](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=metamug_mason&metric=alert_status)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=metamug_mason) 
 [![SonarCloud Coverage](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=metamug_mason&metric=coverage)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/coverage/list?id=metamug_mason)
 [![SonarCloud Bugs](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=metamug_mason&metric=bugs)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/reliability_rating/list?id=metamug_mason)
 [![SonarCloud Vulnerabilities](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=metamug_mason&metric=vulnerabilities)](https://sonarcloud.io/component_measures/metric/security_rating/list?id=metamug_mason)
```

[image: Sonarcloud Status] [image: SonarCloud Coverage]
[image: SonarCloud Bugs]
[image: SonarCloud Vulnerabilities]

Answer (score 12):

https://github.com/030/n3dr

```
[![Bugs](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=bugs)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Code Smells](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=code_smells)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Coverage](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=coverage)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Duplicated Lines (%)](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=duplicated_lines_density)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Lines of Code](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=ncloc)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Maintainability Rating](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=sqale_rating)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Quality Gate Status](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=alert_status)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Reliability Rating](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=reliability_rating)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Security Rating](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=security_rating)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Technical Debt](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=sqale_index)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
[![Vulnerabilities](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=030_n3dr&metric=vulnerabilities)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=030_n3dr)
```

There seems to be 11 badges at the moment.

[image: Bugs]
[image: Code Smells]
[image: Coverage]
[image: Duplicated Lines (%)]
[image: Lines of Code]
[image: Maintainability Rating]
[image: Quality Gate Status]
[image: Reliability Rating]
[image: Security Rating]
[image: Technical Debt]
[image: Vulnerabilities]

Answer (score 2):

I just found this question because i'm also trying to get badges from sonarqube (in my case sonarcloud).

There is an embedded API for badges.
Here is the official documentation (I had some time to find it on google): https://next.sonarqube.com/sonarqube/web_api/api/badges

http://shields.io is unfortunately not working anymore with sonarqube.

Comment: Oh my version 8.5 it's under `/web_api/api/project_badges?internal=true`

Answer (score 2):

Update for June 2018 ...

API was deprecated early 2018 and removed in [April 2018](https://about.sonarcloud.io/news/2018/02/05/new-project-badges.html).

Currently there's a link on a project's lower RHS, "**Get project badges**", which reveals available image urls for metrics.

Answer (score 1):

SonarCloud.io altered API to these urls

```
https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/quality_gate?project=WcfSoapLogger&branch=master
https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=WcfSoapLogger&metric=code_smells
```