# How to add SonarCloud badge on GitHub?

Tags: github, markdown, sonarcloud

I am trying to add `SonarCloud` badge to my `README`.

But when I do like this

```
![https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=com.lapots.breed.judge%3Ajudge-rule-engine](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=com.lapots.breed.judge%3Ajudge-rule-engine&metric=alert_status)
```

The badge itself looks fine but it does not allow to go to `sonarcloud` project and instead leads to `camo.githubusercontent.com`.

Which link should I use to access the `SonarCloud` project?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add SonarQube coverage via shields.io badge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161401/add-sonarqube-coverage-via-shields-io-badge)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The markdown syntax for an image with link is

```
[![<image title>](<image url>)](link url)
```

So, try:

```
[![Sonarcloud Status](https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=com.lapots.breed.judge:judge-rule-engine&metric=alert_status)](https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=com.lapots.breed.judge:judge-rule-engine)
```

Comment: that way it allows to redirect but it doesn't show the badge. I guess I need to access some `svg` somehow directly in the image url

Comment: The above code works perfectly for me. See https://github.com/flopp/scratchpad/blob/master/README.md

Comment: yeah I added accidentally space between `Status] (https`

Answer (score 28):

You can use this link to access SonarCloud project directly:

```
https://sonarcloud.io/dashboard?id=Project_Key_Here
```

Alternatively, you could access your SonarCloud badge via following steps:

1. Open your SonarCloud project
2. Click **Get project badges** button
   [image: SonarCloud project]
3. Copy the badge link based on your selection on **Metric** and **Format**
   [image: Badge]

Answer (score 26):

In new version of sonarcloud.io
You will find badges in overview page by clicking in Information button on left bottom [image]

Comment: Do you know by chance how to change the filetype of the image? It's rendered as SVG, but the slack UI is not displaying it in the notification, so I'd need a jpg/png/whatever instead

Comment: If anyone coming to this answer is unable to find the `Information` button - It now appears to be a link with `Project Information` on the upper right of the project page

Answer (score 1):

As of today, this option is available at the information tab on the sonarcloud, here is ss for my Open source project MSG

[image: SS:]

Comment: But, is it possible get badge for branch? Maybe it shows only main branch status

Comment: @nikli You can append the `branch` parameter to the url: `https://sonarcloud.io/api/project_badges/measure?project=<you-project>&branch=<your-branch>`